# Utilizando ES6 Proxies com ES6 Maps

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estou a mais ou menos 1 dia e meio pesquisando a respeito dos Maps e Proxies para me aprofundar mais na questão de observação de arrays, objetos e etc. 
Mas me deparei com um problema, não consigo utilizar o Proxy no Map. 
Quando se trata de um array comum, consigo utilizar o Proxy sem problemas, mas não sei como fazer de forma correta no caso dos Maps.

```js
let teste = new Map();

let teste_proxy = new Proxy(teste, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {   
    // property is index in this case
   return target[property]
  },
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {    
    target[property] = value;
    // you have to return true to accept the changes
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(teste_proxy);
teste_proxy.set("foo", "bar");
```

Se você executou o código, viu que ele retorna um erro. Acredito que seja pelo fato de ele estar usando a parte do "get" para retornar a função "set" do "Map", mas como retornaria corretamente a função passando os valores adequados a ela ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que `.set` é um método do `Map.prototype`, por isso quando fazes:

```
teste_proxy.set("foo", "bar");
```

ele faz estes passos:

**a):** ir saber o que é `teste_proxy.set`:

ou seja, vai ao objeto que foi passado ao proxy e faz um `get`.
Na prática o mesmo que `var fn = teste.set`

**b):** usar esse valor e invocar uma função em cima dele, ou seja: `fn("foo", "bar")`.

O que é interessante, e talvez confuso, é que ir buscar esse valor, como no exemplo `var fn = teste.set` aciona o `get` do `Proxy`. Ou seja, há um passo entre `a)` e `b)`.

Assim, quando o `Proxy` corre o `get`, pois foi pedido o valor de uma propriedade no objeto que ele está a observar, ele retorna `function set() { [native code] }`. Ou seja o `Prototype` do `Map` => `Map.prototype.set`.

Quando depois chamas

```
var fn = function set() { [native code] }; // isto é sintaxe inválida mas é só para separar em passos
fn('foo', 'bar');
```

o que acontece é o mesmo que fazer:

```
Map.prototype.set('foo', 'bar')
```

e isso dá o mesmo erro que recebeste:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Method Map.prototype.set called on incompatible receiver #
>           at Map.set (native)

#### Então como podemos *settar* valores através do Proxy?

Se fores usar um `Map` podes forçar o contexto de execução dentro do `.get` a ele próprio, assim ele corre o seu método do *Prototype* sobre a instância específica à qual o `Proxy` está assiciado, ou seja usando: `return target[property].bind(target);`. 
Assim quando atribuis um valor com o método `teste_proxy.set` o `Proxy` já não dá bug quando tenta dar de volta o valor de `teste_proxy.set` que precisa de contexto associado para correr.

Exemplo:

```js
let teste = new Map();

let teste_proxy = new Proxy(teste, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {   
    // property is index in this case
   return target[property].bind(target);
  },
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {    
    target[property] = value;
    // you have to return true to accept the changes
    return true;
  }
});

teste_proxy.set("foo", "bar");
console.log(teste_proxy.get("foo"));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Você me ajudou muito.

Comment: @JoaoScheuermann ótimo! Eu demorei também um pouco a perceber o que estava a falhar aí :) Bom ano!

Comment: pra ti também, fiquei horas e horas tentando resolver isso, mas não me veio a cabeça que se tratava do contexto :P